# JAVA_HOME error during installing PySpark on WINDOWS 11 || Error that can shows like that: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver

Tags: pyspark, windows-11, java-home

The solution that worked for me :
please follow all steps to get your error fix.

- Download Java JDK and install it.
- Open a Command Prompt and type **java -version** to make sure you installed java correctly
  [java_version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iRoU.png)
- Now set the **JAVA_HOME** environment variable to point to it.

  - Open Command Prompt to know where java is located by typing **where java**
    [where is java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otUqk.png) 
    In my case java is in :** C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java***\javapath\java.exe*

  -Now go to **Edit the Environment Variables System** in your PC to set the path and your JAVA_HOME.
  [add new Env variable: JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNvtw.png)

  ```
   1. Click on "New" to create your new Environment variable.

   2. Use Variable Name as **JAVA_HOME**

   3. Your Variable Value as Go Now copy and paste the link that you found when you typed **where java** in the previous steps **BUT & BUT** *javapath and java.exe*   then click OK
    In my case : **C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java**
   take a look at the screen below for more understanding.
   [env vriable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXCeZ.png)

  4. Now go to Variable System and select 'Path' and click 'Edit' as shown below.
      [edit path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc8LS.png)
  5. After clicking on Modify in the previous step you now have to add a new variable to the path by clicking new :
    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gZZj.png)
  ```

THE MOST IMPORTANT THING HERE is you have to add **%JAVA_HOME%\javapath** you may notice that I said \javapath to my %JAVA_HOME% in the end and it is so important to do that because it where java file exe located. this file is coming immediately after \java in the link we found by where java command. In another version, it may be **\bin**, if so just do whatever file name that comes after \java in the previous command (where java)
[path java Home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaugO.png)

Then press ok then ok then OK ... et Voilà!

I tried a lot of ways and the previous one worked for me.